# python client reading json list from python server

Tags: python, json

I know there are many json tutorials and Q&A here and on the net, which I've read; but I'm still struggling to get my python script working.

I'm calling a python server program from a client to read a sample list.  My error is:

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: No JSON object could be decoded
 args = ('No JSON object could be decoded',)
 message = 'No JSON object could be decoded'
```

Somewhere in the server I've got the wrong code, which is not taking the list and sending it as a json string.

I'm running everything on a Mongoose webserver.

Server (psptest5.py):

```
#!C:\Mongoose\Python26\python.exe

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import pyodbc
import json
import urllib2
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/"
value= {'customer' : 'Varun Inc','email' : 'varun.verma@varun.com'}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(value), headers=headers)
```

Client(jsonreadtest.py):

```
#!C:\Mongoose\Python26\python.exe

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import json
import urllib2
from pprint import pprint
import csv, sys

url = 'http://localhost:8080/psptest5.py'
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
print data
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server code renders nothing. Try following code (server):

```
#!C:\Mongoose\Python26\python.exe

import json

print 'Content-Type: application/json'
print
print json.dumps({'customer': 'Varun Inc','email': 'varun.verma@varun.com'})
```

Comment: Hello, thanks that works! So json.dumps() acts to send data, while json.load() reads the data.  I was trying to Post data with the Requests module.  Is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your server doesn't seem to be actually *returning* anything, so when your client runs `data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))` it's trying to load JSON from an empty string.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think the server code correct?  If its good, then I'll look further into the Mongoose set-up.